# Visual Studio Express 2012 Desktop With MP4 Video

Tags: visual-studio-2012, desktop-application, mp4

I want to build a desktop application that plays MP4 video files.  I downloaded Visual Studio Express 2012 Desktop Edition and I intend to code it with C#. But, before I start down that road, I want to make sure it's even possible to play MP4 video files in an application built with Visual Studio Express.  If VS doesn't support MP4 files, is it possible to link the desktop app with some third-party player, such as VLC or QuickTime, that will play MP4 files?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio Express itself won't constrain your ability to play MP4 files.  The main difference between the express and non-express SKUs of Visual Studio is simply the set of program editing features they support (more projects, extensions, etc ...).

The playing of an MP4 file is a feature that is provided by a library or the operating system.  Visual Studio won't prevent you from using that library should it exist.  I don't actually know if Windows does this or not, my assumption though is that it does.